# Why Text's width/height and anchors conflict in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I want to specify the width and height of a Text, so that the fontSizeMode:Text.Fit would work. But after that, the anchors of the Text would not work. How could this happen?

```
Rectangle {
    width: 360; height: 360
    Rectangle {
        width: parent.width / 3; height: parent.height / 6
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        border{ color: "red"; width: 5 }
        Text {
            anchors {
                centerIn: parent
//                verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
//                horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            }

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height
            font.pixelSize: 50
            fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
            text: "Hello, world!"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, they are working fine. But since you set width and height, `centrerIn` anchor do not change anything, as text is already in middle of parent. You should set alignment, to get proper effect:

```
Text {
    anchors.fill: parent
    font.pixelSize: 100
    fontSizeMode: Text.Fit
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    text: "Hello, world!"
}
```